# Java Maven Project - Firebase Connection Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getFirst(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
> at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getFromServiceLoader(OAuth2Credentials.java:334)
> ...

Java test case:

```
public void connectToFirebase() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("connectToFirebase()");
    FileInputStream serviceAccount;
    serviceAccount = new FileInputStream
            ("C:\\...\\social-networking-site-ae94d-firebase-adminsdk-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.json");
    Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    auth.put("uid", "my-service-worker");
    System.out.println("-1-"); // error occurred after this line
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://social-networking-site-ae94d.firebaseio.com")
            .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    System.out.println("-2-");
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("/some_resource");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              String res = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                System.out.println(res);
          }
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          }
        });

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.common/google-collect -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of the same library (guava?) because they are in subdependencies of the libraries that your project depends on; method that is missing was added in the newer version, but previous version of the lib is loaded first. So what to do? Skip previous version of the library (guava?) when you define dependency (see maven exclusions), and include the lib (guava?) explicitly in your pom.xml

Comment: I just had a look in my pom.xml and the Maven Dependencies list, I don't see there are multiple versions of any same library being depended on. You mention about guava, but what does it have to do with my project? I only found guava-20.0 in my maven repository folder

Comment: Maybe there is jar that contain dependencies repacked into it. If you are using IDE, could you search for Iterables class and see where it can find it?